# Why <columnname> IS NULL take so long time?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008

I have a test statement to check the validation of my data like this:

```
SELECT id, owner_id 
FROM table 
WHERE ISNULL(owner_id,0)=0
   OR (owner_id NOT IN(SELECT lid FROM actors) AND owner_id <> -65536)
```

OR

```
SELECT id, owner_id 
FROM table 
WHERE owner_id IS NULL
   OR (owner_id NOT IN(SELECT lid FROM actors) AND owner_id <> -65536)
```

Both statement take 1 minute and 45 seconds in my test case to perform.

`owner_id` should be a valid `int` > 0, so my SQL statement should check it toshow me if I have invalid data.

The statement works as expected but it take a very long time.
I added a sql index on that column after the first tries and to see if there is any improvement. No change.

If I just do this:

```
SELECT id, owner_id 
FROM table 
WHERE (owner_id NOT IN(SELECT lid FROM actors) AND owner_id <> -65536)
```

Then the query performs in less then 1 second.

`table` has around 7k records, `actors` around 5k records.

So anyone know why `IS NULL`? validation take such a long time? And can I do any improvements to this?

**EDIT**

```
SELECT id, owner_id 
FROM table 
WHERE ISNULL(owner_id,0)=0
```

Performs in 1 second as well, so it is the combination of the statement that take such a long time.
So it is not the ISNULL validation but kinda a combination in me WHERE statement.

**UPDATED**

Tried @mbeckish suggestion

```
SELECT lid, lownerid 
FROM xapptqadr 
WHERE ISNULL(lownerid,0)=0

UNION

SELECT lid, lownerid 
FROM xapptqadr 
WHERE (lownerid NOT IN(SELECT lid FROM kractor) AND lownerid <> -65536)
```

Will perform in less then 1 second as well as expected.
But I am really overwhelmed by the fact that the `OR` part make such a big difference...

Comment: How is the performance if you UNION the two queries that are performing well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the null check. It's the `OR`. Looking for this OR that in a query often breaks good index usage, resulting in poor performance of the query. Does the following not get the same results?

```
SELECT id, owner_id 
FROM table 
WHERE owner_id NOT IN(SELECT lid FROM actors WHERE lid IS NOT NULL) AND owner_id <> -65536
```

Comment: I understand that the `OR` breaks my performance. but your statement do not give the same results as rows with `owner_id = NULL` will not be part of the result set.

Comment: As there are no other answers and you gave me the right hint about the performance issue I mark this as answer.

Comment: @YvesR don't mark it as the answer if it doesn't work for you. Leaving it unanswered is perfectly okay

Comment: Imho part of the answer was the answer, and due @mbeckish hint I managed a way to improve the performance.